# Basis change in the context of the Schroedinger and Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, unitarity

I am trying to understand the following statement:

One sometimes summarizes this situation with the slogan: In the Schr¨odinger picture
the basis vectors (provided by the observables) are fixed, while the state vector evolves
in time. In the Heisenberg picture the state vectors are held fixed, but the basis vectors
evolve in time (in the inverse manner). This is an instance of the “active vs. passive”
representation of a transformation — in this case time evolution.

I want to mathematically show what is being described above but I am not sure whether I achieve in doing so or not. Also one thing that I find hard to understand, is how in the Heisenberg picture even though the basis kets are time-dependent, the state in this picture, which can be expressed as a linear combination of the basis kets (which are time-dependent) is not?

We have: $A|\phi_n\rangle=n|\phi_n\rangle$

In Schrodinger picture:

$|\psi(t)\rangle =\sum_n c_n(t_0)e^{-\frac{iE_n(t-t_0)}{\hbar}}|\phi_n\rangle$

$|\psi(t)\rangle =\sum_n c_n(t)|\phi_n\rangle$

Here we can see that the state vector is time-dependent while the basis kets are not. So I believe, that I correctly translate mathematically the initial part of the statement.

Than in the Heisenberg picture at some arbitrary time t:

$|\psi(t)\rangle_H=\sum_n c_n(t_0)e^{-\frac{iE_n(t-t_0)}{\hbar}}|\phi_n\rangle$

$|\psi(t)\rangle_H=\sum_n c_n(t_0)|\phi_n(t)\rangle$

But at the same time when we move from the Schroedinger picture to the Heisenberg one we do:

$|\psi(t)\rangle_H=U(t,t_0)^\dagger |\psi(t)\rangle=U^{\dagger} U |\psi(t_0)\rangle$.

So I don't know how to show the 2nd part of the statement.

Comment: You are unequivocally cool with [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture), right? One rarely represents Heisenberg operators through ket spectral decomposition...

Comment: I am ok with WP in general, but I just wanted to mathematically translate the above statement

Comment: I'd start by working with the (time-independent) hamiltonian eigenkets, not your operator's eigenkets.

Comment: I am assuming that the operator commutes with the Hamiltonian

Comment: Bit if it did, the Heisenberg operator would *coincide* with the Schroedinger one, and the heisenberg equations of motion would trivialize. Did you read the WP article cited?

Comment: Why would it coincide?

Comment: Because the Heisenberg equations of motion would dictate that the Heisenberg operator is constant. It's in WP... You are chasing a canard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148424/discussion-between-imbaf-and-cosmas-zachos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But at the same time when we move from the Schröedinger picture to the Heisenberg one we do:
>
> $|ψ(t)⟩_H=U(t,t_0)^†|ψ(t)⟩=U^†U|ψ(t_0)⟩$.
>
> So I don't know how to show the 2nd part of the statement.

Careful here. Actually we have $|ϕ(t)⟩_H = U(t,t_0)^†|ϕ(t_0)⟩$. We are dealing with *base* kets, not with the state ket. Remember that the base kets become *time dependent* and that the whole state is now *time independent*.

The correct way to see the state in the Heisenberg picture would be

$|ψ(t)⟩ = ∑_n c_n(t) |ϕ_n⟩ = ∑_n c_n(t) e^{-i \frac{E_n (t−t_0)}{ℏ}} e^{i \frac{E_n (t−t_0)}{ℏ}}  |ϕ_n⟩,$

$|ψ(t)⟩ = ∑_n c_n(t) e^{-i \frac{E_n (t−t_0)}{ℏ}} |ϕ_n (t)⟩_H,$

$|ψ(t)⟩ = ∑_n c_n(t) U\, |ϕ_n (t)⟩_H = U \, ∑_n c_n(t)\, |ϕ_n (t)⟩_H$.

Now, we have $|ψ⟩_H = U^† |ψ(t)⟩$. So $|ψ⟩_H = \, ∑_n c_n(t)\, |ϕ_n (t)⟩_H$. But remember that $|ϕ_n (t)⟩_H = e^{\mathbf{+} i \frac{E_n (t−t_0)}{ℏ}} |ϕ_n⟩ $ (with a POSITIVE sign). So there is no temporal dependence in $|ψ⟩_H$.

You might wonder what happened to the temporal dependece? This is actually present in the *observables* instead that in the state. Now the observable $A$ would be - in the Heisenberg picture - $A_H (t) = U^† A (t_0) U$.

Check that we retrieve $\langle ψ_H | A_H(t) |ψ⟩_H = \langle ψ (t) | U A_H(t) U^† |ψ(t)⟩ = \langle ψ (t) | A |ψ(t)⟩ = a(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are assuming that the Hamiltonian is time independent right?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that much would change with a time dependent H(t). I am a bit rusty, so don't trust me 100%!